# In R, why are list(1:3) and list("a", "b","see") of different lengths?

Tags: r, list

In R, why does `list(1:3)` produce a list of length 1, but `list("a","b","see")` produces a list of length 3?

Comment: `1:3` is a shorthand for `c(1, 2, 3)`. `list(1:3)` creates a list of one item: the vector `c(1, 2, 3)`. `list("a", "b", "see")` creates a list of 3 elements. I'd recommend digging through your code and experimenting with what's in each of your variables as a way of doing some research first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the number of arguments.  In the first, there is only a single argument and in the second, it is three and each argument would be an element in the `list`.  To convert to length 3 by passing a single arugment, use the `as.`

```
as.list(1:3)
```

Comment: @IamWill yes, but that would be 3 arguments as I mentioned `list(1, c('a', 'b'), data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6))`